# Updatable promises using proxy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise, metaprogramming, service-worker

**EDIT**: I've updated this question, and the **old** question is moved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76360616/8791684).

A POC can be found on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phonetically_SAARTHaK/1t4evdrf/)
or the snippet below

---

**GOAL:**

The goal here is to make or rather *simulate* a promise that can be updated, whose lifecycle can be essentially reset.

Optionally, I wanted more control over promise resolution using *inversion of control*, like this:

```js
const ex = {};
  const prom = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
    ex.resolve = resolve;
    ex.reject = reject;
  });
```

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

Snippet:

You can type in the new value, and choose whether to reject or resolve the promise. Rejected values will be highlighted.

> By default the promise is rejected with a value `default`.

**Edit**: By default, there's a `.then()` callback attached (line 85 in snippet). So once you resolve or reject with a value for the **first** time, you'll see your value printed **twice**, which is the expected behavior.

```js
class UpdatablePromise {
  /**
   * @param prom - the default promise object
   * @param executor - optional ExternalExecutor argument to store executor internally.
   * @returns UpdatablePromise
   */
  constructor(prom, executor) {
    this.value = undefined;
    this.executors = [];
    if (executor) this.executors.push(Object.assign({}, executor));
    /**
     * Call previous resolve/reject functions to fulfil previous promises, if any.
     * helper function, just to reduce code duplication in `update` function.
     */
    const prevResolvers = (type) => {
      return (val) => {
        const flag = type === "reject";
        while (true) {
          const executor = this.executors.shift();
          if (executor) flag ? executor.reject(val) : executor.resolve(val);
          else break;
        }
        return val;
      };
    };
    const handler = {
      get: (target, prop) => {
        // console.log(prop);
        if (prop === "update") {
          // return a function which takes the new promise value and its executor as argument
          return (v, executor) => {
            // console.log('upd', v, this.value);
            this.value = v;
            if (executor) this.executors.push(executor);
            // attach `then` function to the new promise, so that the old promises are fulfilled when the new one does
            // this has no effect on already fulfilled promises.
            v.then(
              (val) => prevResolvers("resolve")(val),
              (val) => prevResolvers("reject")(val)
            );
          };
        } else if (typeof this.value === "undefined") {
          // if value is undefined, i.e. promise was never updated, return default property values
          return typeof target[prop] === "function" ?
            target[prop].bind(target) :
            target[prop];
        }
        // else,  attach functions to new promise
        else if (prop === "then") {
          //   console.log('then', this.value);
          return (onfulfilled, onrejected) =>
            this.value.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
        } else if (prop === "catch") {
          return (onrejected) => this.value.catch(onrejected);
        } else if (prop === "finally") {
          return (onfinally) => this.value.finally(onfinally);
        } else return target[prop];
      },
    };
    return new Proxy(prom, handler);
  }
}



const input = document.getElementById("input")
const output = document.getElementById("output")
const resBtn = document.getElementById("res")
const rejBtn = document.getElementById("rej")


const ex_1 = {
  resolve: () => void 0,
  reject: () => void 0,
};

const prom_1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  ex_1.resolve = resolve;
  ex_1.reject = reject;
});

const up = new UpdatablePromise(prom_1, ex_1)

// Await the promise
up.then(_ => print(_), _ => print(_))

// Print the value of promise, highlight if it is rejected
async function print() {
  try {
    const val = await up;

    output.innerHTML += `
${val}`

  } catch (e) {
    output.innerHTML += `
<mark>${e}</mark>`
  }
}


resBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  up.update(Promise.resolve(input.value));
  print();
})


rejBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  up.update(Promise.reject(input.value));
  print();
})


function consoleTest() {
  const ex = {
    resolve: () => void 0,
    reject: () => void 0,
  };

  const prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ex.resolve = resolve;
    ex.reject = reject;
  });

  const up = new UpdatablePromise(prom, ex);

  setTimeout(() => ex.resolve("resolved"), 1000);

  up.then(
    (_) => console.log(_, "res"),
    (_) => console.log(_, "rej")
  );

  setTimeout(async() => {
    up.update(Promise.reject("reject"));
    up.then(
      (_) => console.log(_, "res"),
      (_) => console.log(_, "rej")
    );
  }, 2000);
  setTimeout(async() => {
    up.update(Promise.resolve("res again"));
    up.then(
      (_) => console.log(_, "res"),
      (_) => console.log(_, "rej")
    );
  }, 2500);
}

consoleTest();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="input">Enter a value to update promise with:</label>
  <input id="input" />

  <div>
    <button id="res">
        resolve
      </button>

    <button id="rej">
        reject
      </button>
  </div>
  <pre id="output"></pre>
</body>

</html>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phonetically_SAARTHaK/1t4evdrf/)

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHsCAnAdgQwDbwgYwK7AD2SAPACoB8UAvFAN4BQUUSEAzoRgG4QBcUACi6Y8fKGSgAfKAAUkhALYBLNhAAySgNYRyFAJQ0qXQkoAmAbiYsIAK1zB+QkWInS5ileq07KB6kZMLBgBfSwYAegAqSNl5ZVU2KGAACzRgKBw0FCg8MFM0iFMkwihTJQAzcuQIFHThDFEAGigsoswMJOToSBQylABzKAADNAB3NCVgIcTRpQwOgCNoXPzENpmIeYA6JhiAIQhUnkSbPDZ0jG8odGAlHigwOM82XfCGJVrkcrQcaABVPJpNALDAQdzxHxUCAIGqmRLgzy6ehWKKRKxQNHMDFQAACYDQSDQCigXHEXWuEFGsQ8qnRMTxBKJUGhuAIxCghDAt0I6A6LPwRCQUHK7JSKgeT1pWMib2YKwKQn4CNUuma-LZSAA-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-hABitQNg3fuklFoTR+FCYRWxsEt5TAAIomOZJ5ECJRBgjWggyamBGpbLNE5dQY-CUR9eVqd983bZsqhQAsrBoJowMIVa23WPeqAxhgMNQKEOHo2lu1QKkvSgkgwFwCAAASrT4yQbq6FQtBbVi-QQA4xUEvTwDNG2YD8NoICEOU1IQgmdWxRATWGP1A3hOEX4GZwEBbBghD9IB8hgNd8N3ezNDTWVQsi7T4uS+1SNoAlnnZItSg4MkSRQ+w3YUlS1lgyh0CtB6-pvae9qbtuu6TvDzCG51XDAfzlCCXOWpFlBBrHRW+ii3r20S1Lqmy-Liva3kZXNFwzSHc7qv+8w+fOGhXCowNd0PbhR0R-RjH3bHhdF8naRBpbwwpDU8Xuab+5d-bEpvs0HCdGkducEUju2wS0A6RgpmgkUi01HbWFUjyPaEOwN367hONeygJQplUE4ctkmCQ6YIDGQvcxL0PEJ4bvklcFsXe8S-A3faL5k5QDBU2ACHqlVYWehvqNC-pJH+-g5L-1AYVYBn1gBNQgVA5gzdtro3hsEZkGAwZ3QmjzGuztNa0G1hhNMphdZQOTuRUh4oky9kwoUWy+EtiP08FAcYiQsIFRyIGVhCMOqlD7AOTKnJkCgGRqIF4RdA5JHABAYhQYtwM0rOzasZC6q9yXGVdBUBXqrWZuozRLREgADFdJLj0FsBYHxTDGLUcAPQBj+CqJZho5WtYX5wyTpLUGEBmgtGAO3K2uj9KGRKOvThUoQb4OgOrZW2iyofxofDZOO1pagjlgrYBaS85LTwgXCuWIFECAMTyeei9CgQQEF1UQPU+quD5oiXwtUmEpiobVFAA4MCQKLswHkyDamOAEJDDgKB+D2WabVSm7TEyUKwkUaQvT5gDP9n1VaRTkKly9vM-Q78ui8SqSZe+QjhkNQnIUTBsM8EEN5krTkKTIqW3Sf7cplSUAjNMHU8ZEB7Q8mmSgEAsy3DxgWehZh3TVl9I2fDLZJcGgu3hBCw5rymKXK0jc0puDAkekeRrKa5DMLtBAO8+G5SqkfDJX8vq5pTAGEWdC5ZPS+nNQMdspCpD9lotsaS+YIABDUt5JeW5WI8UJOEUjDxpjvGowEhjMSAcGYiJie4ImTyFDNFxqYfGBgvZJk0EfUYF8nxAhfAc0iVorQ2mxtCKOyBoIRxID+D4-RqZixUvlMQV1RYMqgAABnhdYLSjh6WBCDSEMSQ0JHEloOq+MbqBgUHqZVH1zRkF9VptCf6oC0LprUsDXNyCC1XOANa66VhY0CLQjEp0FrXShi1YJKtzBVDADIJ6ZRBB6l9RLQAiAAgABEhaeCmGHXoZoABGQNc7C5DRlrkxWYwJjpFyK4hgHau2+iUpde0IAPKCGzThXIWwhYCDdP9LSI7kGTswYunJ6cBCrsmAI1xAkoAACY52BsLtabd3a90vrYIenAx6E6nrAOewRl7Qx5p9beme-QJgoHvcDR9ac8mvvXSrEIzQv0AFZ52kWtNaZg0IwDEHSPxIAA) - ts version (may not be updated. Prefer fiddle version)

Here's the part that prints the promise's value:

```js
// Print the value of promise, highlight if it is rejected
async function print() {
  try {
    const val = await up;

    output.innerHTML += `
${val}`

  } catch (e) {
    output.innerHTML += `
<mark>${e}</mark>`
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**:

It *seems* to work *sometimes*, for example, in console or in the fiddle.

But doesn't actually work when I use it in the service worker, only the old value of the promise is returned, . I'm using workbox, if that's relevant.

I'm yet to pinpoint the problem. So here's the actual workbox code that doesn't work for me:

```js
// If the refresh Token is resolved, the user is logged in, otherwise not.
class MyStrat extends Strategy {
  async _handle() {
    try {
      await refreshToken;

      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ is_logged_in: true }), {
        status: 200,
        headers: [[CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON]],
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error', e);
      return new Response(JSON.stringify({ is_logged_in: false }), {
        status: 400,
        headers: [[CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON]],
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**PRECISE QUESTION:**

I'd like to know a few things:

1. Does it really work as mentioned above?
   (i.e. It works exactly like a promise, with the exception that it
   can be "reset" and once it is updated, all pending `await`s or
   attached callbacks fulfil with the new updated value)
2. If yes, then what could be the reason that it doesn't work in (workbox's) service worker.
3. If no, then what's actually happening?
4. If it really does work, then is it possible to add a `state` member variable to synchronously keep track of promise state? (I tried it once, didn't work at all)

Edit 2:

Apparently this actually does seem to work in service worker as well. The promise was getting updated to value stored in database repeatedly due to some other functions.

However, I'd still like to get an answer for my other questions

Comment: No. Promises are not updatable. They resolve once, and then they keep that single value. Do not subclass `Promise`, and do not violate the LSP. You do not want to update the promise object, you simply want to reassign the `token` variable.

Comment: Using a proxy doesn't event make sense here. Please use normal subclassing with overridden methods, the code is not readable otherwise.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. but reassigning token would probably not work for pending requests. I know promises can't be updated. that's why I've used a proxy. It isn't really a promise, but assigns a new promise via the `update` function. 

I've added types and comments for more clarity, Maybe I should add a short summary of my attempt as well.

Comment: I don't understand why it works in the browser console but not with when I use in the service worker (workbox)

Comment: *What* works in the browser console?

Comment: "*reassigning token would probably not work for pending requests*" - pending requests would have used the previous value of the promise, which is just what you would want.

Comment: @Bergi I want requests to wait while the new token is being fetched, and automatically use the new value once the new token is fetched.

Comment: Exactly. Once you fetch a new token, and assign the promise for the token to the variable, all subsequent requests can wait for that new token. If you need help with this, you should show us the relevant part of your code that does this.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I may need help with that. I'll add a minimal example in my queation.

Regarding the console part - the code [here](https://pastebin.com/J2RwVVZM) works as expected when you run it in browser directly

Comment: "*it can be "reset" and once it is updated, all pending `await`s or attached callbacks fulfil with the new updated value*" - your examples don't really show how that is supposed to work. You never update an `UpdatablePromise` that is still pending. Also you never update them to a pending promise, but only to already settled ones.

Comment: @Bergi edited again

Comment: @Bergi could you edit the title to be more specific, since Proxy is irrelevant now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it really work like I'm expecting it to work in the console or fiddle?

Only you can tell whether it does what you are expecting. But given you say it works, in the console, in the fiddle, and (according to your edit) also in the service worker, it seems that yes it does work.

However, there is no good reason to use a `Proxy` here. The implementation becomes much cleaner if you use a regular class instance that is wrapping a promise:

```
class UpdatableResource {
  /**
   * @param prom - the default promise object
   * @param resolver - optional resolver function to resolve the promise when updating.
   */
  constructor(prom, resolver) {
    this.value = Promise.resolve(prom);
    this.handlers = [];
    if (resolver) this.handlers.push(resolver);
  }
  /**
   * Call previous resolve/reject functions to fulfil previous promises, if any.
   * helper function, just to reduce code duplication in `update` function.
   */
  _runHandlers(val) {
    while (this.handlers.length) {
      const handler = this.handlers.shift();
      handler(val);
    }
  }
  /* a function which takes the new promise value and its executor as argument */
  update(v, handler) {
    // console.log('upd', v, this.value);
    this.value = Promise.resolve(v);
    // resolve the old promise(s) to the new one, so that the old promises are fulfilled when the new one does
    this._runHandlers(v);
    if (handler) this.handlers.push(handler);
  }
  then(onfulfilled, onrejected) {
    return this.value.then(onfulfilled, onrejected);
  }
  catch(onrejected) {
    return this.value.catch(onrejected);
  }
  finally(onfinally) {
    return this.value.finally(onfinally);
  }
}
```

> Is it possible to add a `state` member variable to synchronously keep track of promise state?

Sure, just add

```
this.state = "pending";
this.value.then(() => {
  this.state = "fulfilled";
}, () => {
  this.state = "rejected";
});
```

after each assignment of a promise to `this.value` (or better yet, put it in a helper method).

Comment: If I swap your definition in the fiddle, it doesn't produce the same result (renaming the class as `UpdatablePromise`).

Comment: I've edited the quoted part to make it more clear. Although I believe I clearly specified what my GOAL is.

Comment: Notice I simplified the "executor" handler mechanism. [The fiddle works just fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/5x70gfuk/).

Comment: Missed that part. it works as expected. But there would be no way to reject the promise via the resolver, right? Although it's fine, it was optional anyway.

Comment: You can reject the promise by resolving it to a rejected promise (see the fiddle code).

Comment: Got it. Didn;t know it's possible to reject via resolve function as well

Comment: The synchronous state check works as well. This is great

Comment: One last thing, if even this could be done via "normal" subclassing, then what is the actual use of `Proxy`?

Comment: The use of proxies is for when you need to hook on lower-level things than just property access (which a getter could do as well), and when you don't know the property names that you want to hook on.