# Service Worker Architecture: Efficient Token Handling and Network Request Synchronization

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, es6-promise, service-worker

TL;DR: I need a mechanism to hold auth token for my application in a service worker, which will be used by network requests. This token will be updated periodically (15 min). If the token is currently being fetched, all the **new** network requests should **wait** for the token to be fetched, and use the new value of the token.

---

> I'm building an webapp in which authentication is handled via tokens. Since this application is only supposed to be used as a native app (using TWA), I wanted to utilize the service worker for handling network requests.

**Requirements:**

- Service Worker boots up and fetches the token for the first time, and stores it in a variable in memory.
- Network requests use this token for authorization.
- If there were some requests made **while** the token was being fetched, they should wait for the token to be fetched, and then continue once the token is updated.
- Similarly, the same should happen when the token is fetched again, after a certain short interval. The token life cycle is essentially *reset*.

The closest approach is to use Promises, but since promises can't be updated, I've tried using [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to achieve this effect.

Here's my attempt at that: [Updatable promises using proxy in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76360105/updatable-promises-using-proxy-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment134651128_76360105)

It maybe best achieved with some modified form of 'Observables', but I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

No need to mutate the promise object itself - which is impossible, once it's locked in to a value it will keep that. You can just replace it with a different promise. Network requests would use the promise currently stored in the variable - which is either already fulfilled, or a pending promise while the token is being updated, so they just wait for that.

```
async function getToken() { … }
let tokenPromise = getToken();
setInterval(() => {
  tokenPromise = getToken();
}, 15*60*1000);
async function request(…) {
  const token = await tokenPromise;
  return fetch(… token …);
}
```

<sub>(You also need to consider error handling, if `getToken()` fails it would store a rejected promise and prevent `request` from working for the next 15min. I'd put `tokenPromise = null` instead and re-try `getToken()` on the first request that needs it, also re-scheduling the interval.)</sub>

Comment: I initially thought of doing it this way, but there's some more more implementation details to it. There are 2 tokens, refresh and access, with the usual meaning respectively. Also, a new service worker gets the access token of the last active service worker. Can I be *really* sure that there won't be any sideffects of replacing the promise object itself?

Comment: For example, the case when the token is in pending state but it is later updated to another promise. In that case, won't the request made with the old pending promise will be waiting forever?    Since the promise may never fulfill? Although I realise it's impractical for that to happen.

Comment: No, the request that waited for the old pending promise is still waiting for that promise object, and will run once that promise fulfills. It doesn't matter whether the promise is still stored in the `tokenPromise` variable or not when it fulfills, there may as well be a new promise in the variable for new requests to be used. If the promise never fulfills, something is wrong with `getToken`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sideffects".

Comment: Is it possible to make requests made with old pending promise fulfill with the new value? That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: side effects: requests pending forever.

Comment: Unless you are making multiple concurrent `getToken()` calls, there will be no more old pending promises once you get a new value, there will only be an old fulfilled promise. And no, there will be no requests that are pending forever.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I'll accept the answer once I've cleared out 1-2 suspicious (though rare) edge cases I can think of.